# returning an IF statment without closing a loop event filter pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a number of frames that are made depending on the number of items in a list. I want to click on this frame to expand it to have more options. I have installed an event filter on the frame. I have been making the frames like this:

```
        for num, i in enumerate(self.data):

            exec(f"self.frame_user_{num} = QFrame(self.frame_user_frame)")                 
            getattr(self, f"frame_user_{num}").setMouseTracking(True)
            getattr(self, f"frame_user_{num}").installEventFilter(self)
```

and it works fine.

when it comes to the event filter

```
    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        loop_length = len(self.data)
        z = 0
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            while z < loop_length:
                if object == getattr(self, f"frame_user_{z}"):
                    self.expand_buttons(z)
                else:
                    return False
                z += 1
        else:
            return False
```

The problem I have is I need to close the if statement in the loop with an else: return False otherwise I get the error:

a 'bool' is expected not 'NoneType'

but if I put the else: return false it ends the loop and doesn't go through the rest of the frames.

How would I write the event filter so It goes through each frame without closing the loop and not giving an error?

or is there another better way?

Comment: Could you make this a [MRE]? It's impossible to test as-is, and hard to tell what exactly you actually want to happen. What *do* you want to happen for non-mouse-click events?

Comment: The while-loop is totally unnecessary. All you need to do is add a property to the frames when they're created: `frame = QFrame(self.frame_user_frame); frame.setProperty('z', num); frame.setMouseTracking(True); frame.installEventFilter(self); setattr(self, f"frame_user_{num}", frame)`. Then in the event-filter you can simply do: `z = object.property('z')`. If the property isn't set, `z` will be `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get to the end of the `while` loop without executing `else: return False`, you'll exit the function without an explicit `return` statement. Put another `return` after the loop.

```
def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    loop_length = len(self.data)
    if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
        for z in range(loop_length):
            if object == getattr(self, f"frame_user_{z}"):
                self.expand_buttons(z)
            else:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I return `True` there since all the other paths return `False`, so I assume this is considered the successful case.

However, I'm not sure that your loop is doing what you really want. It will return `False` immediately if `object` is not the same as `self.frame_user_0`, so you won't keep searching for other matching attributes. I suspect what you want is:

```
for z in range(loop_length):
    if object == getattr(self, f"frame_user_{z}"):
        self.expand_buttons(z)
        return True
return False
```

This will look for the first `frame_user_{z}` attribute that matches object, expand it, and return `True`. If none are found, it will return `False`.

Comment: yes, The Event filter works so long as I click on frame_user_0, if I click on one of the others the loop closes before it has a chance to get to them.

I dont know why I didn't think of putting return True just outside the loop but it works perfectly now. I removed the else: return False inside the loop and put return False just outside the loop and now its working perfectly, Thanks